# How to mock input arguments into a method in python

Tags: python, unit-testing, testing, mocking, patch

```
def generate_file(config: dict): -> None:
    ...
    my_obj = create_my_obj(config)
    my_obj_binary = my_obj.export()
    write_file(my_obj_binary, "some_path", mode="wb")

def create_my_obj(config: dict) -> MyObj:
   # some configuration checking etc.
   ...
   ...
   
   return MyObj(opt1="something", opt2="something_else", value="VALUE_TO_MOCK")


# TEST
def test_my_obj():
   config = ... # get config data from json or whatever...

   generate_file(config)
   
   # load a golden sample binary
   ...
   # load binary generated by my file
   ...

   # compare those two
   assert golden_sample_binary == generated_binary
```

Above is a snippet of my code I'm testing. My code generates a binary file and I need to compare this binary file with a golden sample to test, whether my code generates the file properly. I need to "mock" one input argument to a very specific value in **MyObj()** invoked in **create_my_obj()**. I'm using unittest library, unfortunately I'm not able to figure this out.

Thanks for any hints

Comment: When you say 
*I need to "mock" one input argument to a very specific value in MyObj() invoked in create_my_obj()*

By **value** do you just mean mock an attribute?  if so you can do an arbitrary assignment to the attribute using `MyObj.attribute = "value"` inline

Comment: From "test_my_obj(  )" I don't have access to "MyObj" class to be able to do so. By default MyObj( ) set's "value" to None, whereas I need it to be let's say '1234'. I could do what you propose in "create_my_obj", but that would modify my code permanently, not just for testing.

Comment: I see, so my_obj is being serialized and then you are checking the file in the test. If you know what value should be you can add a  line after `my_obj = create_my_obj(config)` that just has `my_obj.value = "1234"` which means it will be baked into the export for you.

Comment: Still the same problem, `generate_file( )` can't be modified this way, as it's part of the "API" to say. I need to do it from `test_my_obj`. So my idea was, "redefine" **MyObj** in a way, where **value** wouldn't be **None** by default, but '1234' and I thought mocking MyObj could work, but can't figure out how.

Comment: I see, you can use mock objects with the mock library (https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.mock.html#the-mock-class). I haven't done it with a class so I unfortunately can't help you, but it's probably the right place to start looking. Otherwise the `Patch the function's __defaults__ attribute` section of this article might help https://mdawar.dev/blog/mock-python-default-function-argument

Comment: Looks interesting, thanks for the link! Let's see, whether I found something interesting in there. :-)

Answer (score 1):

So based on @Kiearan Wood link, the solution is to patch the defaults of the **init** method using mock.patch.object.

```
import unittest.mock as mock

def test_my_obj():
   config = ... # get config data from json or whatever...

   new_defaults = list(MyObj.__init__.__defaults__)
   # The value to mock is the last in the list...
   new_defaults[-1] = "value to mock"
   new_defaults = tuple(new_defaults)

   with mock.patch.object(MyObj.__init__, "__defaults__", new_defaults):
       generate_file(config)
   
   # load a golden sample binary
   ...
   # load binary generated by my file
   ...

   # compare those two
   assert golden_sample_binary == generated_binary
```

Thank you very much for the link, which helped a lot!! :-)